# How to craft container for cooking and filtering/purifying water

Tags: survival, cooking

If a scenario in which you go in the forest or next to one, how are you supposed to craft a containers?

All the web-ressources I can find for filtering water thanks to the multi-layer rocks (from fine sand to charcoal/rocks) will need a container. Either something metallic, a can, or a simple bottle cut in half. But you don't find that far away from human presence. *Well, you might with all the debris left by our specie, but for the sake of the question let's assume you are somewhere you can't find it*.

To boil water to purify it, you also need a container. Most of time, it's assumed you have a metallic pot, but blacksmithing isn't a step you'll take before achieving to have clean water.

Same for cooking tutorials : "take your fish, put it in the pot, easy peasy"

**So my question is :**

1/ How do you craft a container that can be use for filtering water?

2/How do you craft a container that can be heated to boil water and cook?

*3/ This one is a bit off topic here, but where can I find some ressources about survival from scratch and not "survival from scratch but only if you already have a a supermarket next door"*?

**EDIT :**

Comments and vote cast are the proof I haven't been clear. I'm not looking for method to purify or filter water. I'm looking for a way to **craft** the container needed for thoses actions **and cooking**. And these **without going to a supermarket** or taking something in my house that I got in a supermarket

Comment: First link say I should have a trash bag. And I don't know how to craft that. Second link say I should boil for one minute, but not how to craft the recipe. 
Third link use a water bottle and explain the method I explain in the question.
Fourth link might be what I was looking for, but not for the cooking recipe.

Comment: @Roflo Yes! Thank you, mixed up with my language.

Comment: I though so. My french is rusty, but the Spanish word for container is "recipiente", so I figured it was likely to be a translation issue. @CharlieBrumbaugh does your VTC still hold after last edit?

Comment: Fair enough. T.Nel, is there something in your question that remains unanswered from the last link that @CharlieBrumbaugh  provided? If so, could you edit your question to address it specifically?

Comment: @Roflo Yes, most of it. But probably because this question isn't fitted for SE and should maybe be closed has too broad. (The dupe is about purifying water by boiling. Answer about how to do it with similar method without boiling, and my question is also about cooking and filtering container, which differ from purifying). Either it should be closed as too broad, either I should remove it (as I'm not sure it will help someone doing a research in the future), either I should give it a 24 hour shot at finding an answer. If somebody want to reply to this comment, maybe it should be in discussion.

Comment: @T.Nel I was starting to write up an answer, but I found that many of the things I would say overlapped heavily with the accepted answer to "How do you boil water without a proper container?", so I would suggest this is a duplicate. **However**, if you are interested in having a reusable, long lasting, heat resistant container, you should look into 2 things: 1) How to make your own clay from dirt, and 2) How to fire clay in a fire. #1 can be very time consuming; do not assume that your survival pottery will be ready in your first day or two. For #2, make a few in case some break in the fire.

Comment: @T.Nel Also note: Your question itself might not be a duplicate of that other question at first glance, since you are asking "How do I make a container?" while the other question asks "How do I do it without a proper container?" but the answers to that question are answers to your question too, and that is why people are calling it duplicate.